# How to color half icon using ReactJS and Font-awesome?

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I want to display some icons from font-awesome for a rating system.
At this point I just want to display the result but I didn't find how to colour only half of the star icon.

For instance, if the rate is 3.5 I would display 3 yellow stars, 1 half star in yellow and the rest in grey.

Is there a way to do it with reactjs Font-aweosome component (
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';)?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46686143/8620333

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to color half of the fontawesome icons but you can try using [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tgeorgetom/7u2L6wnt/2/) technique.

```css
.header_star{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.header_star .fa.fa-star{
  font-size: 20px;
}
.header_star:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header_star .star_hover .fa.fa-star {
  color: #ffd200;
}
.star_hover {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}
.header_star:hover .star_hover {
  width: 92%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="header_star">
  <a href="#" class="header_star"> 
    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="star_hover">          
      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```